# Direct solving of Bellman optimality equation

Tags: reinforcement-learning, bellman-equations

I'm reading the Sutton and Barto second edition (the 2020 revision). I'm on chapter 3.6 "Optimal Policies and Optimal Value Functions".

It is suggested that the Bellman optimality equations could be solved.

> The Bellman optimality equation is actually a system
> of equations, one for each state, so if there are n states, then there
> are $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns. If the dynamics $p$ of the environment
> are known, then in principle one can solve this system of equations
> for $v_*$ using any one of a variety of methods for solving systems of
> nonlinear equations. One can solve a related set of equations for $q_*$.

And a bit later:

> Explicitly solving the Bellman optimality equation provides one route to finding an
> optimal policy, and thus to solving the reinforcement learning problem.

I'm wondering what kind of techniques and solvers could be used to solve the Bellman optimality equations for the state-value function. These equations being mostly linear with a $max$ operator kinda remind me of linear programming. But I'm not sure how to formulate the problem this way since the $max$ here are operators, not an objective function.

Note : I know this cannot work for decent-sized MDP, that's not really the question here.

Comment: Interesting answer. (I didn't find it because it wasn't tagged [bellman-equations].) I thought of a formulation like this, but it's not obvious to me why we can minimize the $\sum_s v*(s)$ when what we want is to minimize them all independently.

Comment: You could ask another question. Btw, if your question here is different, you should edit it to clarify how it's different ;)